# Using GAPI ( Google Analytics API ), how can I find unique visitors?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

How can I find unique visitors using gapi?

At Google Analytics, I used custom report and added 'Unique Visitors' as Metric and 'Page' as dimension and I am able to see the report. After applying filter, I can see unique visitor of each page and also Unique Visitors overall. But, I am not able to do so using gapi.

Comment: I think another article covers this topic.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165079/create-report-with-pageviews-and-unique-visitors-using-gapi

Comment: Does it mean GAPI does not allow it and there is no way to get it through the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I wish I had a better answer for you. It looks like Google saves themselves the computation by limiting which results the API can return. However, the article states that for many reason, visits will give you more meaningful data.

Comment: is there any way ( using API), we may get visits, not of each page, but of a set of pages ( as returned by the filter ). I see it in report at the top but how can we get that through GAPI?

Comment: So from what I can gather you would like to take a group of pages and return their total visits from the API?

Comment: Yes, and the solution I have found is that I should just calculate the sum of it ( pagepath == 'ABC') and it will work fine as visits are mutually exclusive if I retrieve pagepath and visits. Right?

Comment: And the second way could be using segments but I guess for my probleb, just filteration will work. Please advise.

Comment: Please read:
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDataFeed.html#filters

This article states that you can use the OR keyword to specify multiple filters. This would allow you to return the visits formore than one page at once. You could then sum them to get a total.